# SSH connection problem - allowed from LAN but not WAN

Tags: ssh, arch-linux

I tried to setup my Arch Linux installation to be an SSH host, but here is the thing:

I can `ssh localhost`, it fails to login via public key and asks for username and password, but still able to login.

When I try `ssh my_wan_ip` it gives `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` error. I've read all topics about this error and none helped me. By the way, just confirmed, it gives `ssh: connect to host my_dyndns_hostname port 22: Connection refused` from another machine (outside of my network, it has different wan ip).

I have `sshd: ALL` in "hosts.allow", `ALL:ALL` in "hosts.deny".
I am able to connect to my own pc via ssh, ping my own pc, but my ssh setup seems to be the problem, it gives that annoying error when I try to ssh from wan.

[/etc/ssh/ssh_config](http://pastebin.com/Q6RAt7gJ)
[/etc/ssh/sshd_config](http://pastebin.com/Hr5fnRGt)

And finally, here is the debug output for both sshd and ssh: (i ran ssh command and i took output to sshd debug after that):

[sshd debug](http://pastebin.com/jwgBmEFR)
[ssh debug](http://pastebin.com/w5HcMKXg)

I can edit my question according to your needs. Just ask for any more information needed. BTW I have no iptables running. I have one cable dsl modem connected to a asus wl-330gE wireless access point, they both have their firewall disabled. I configured NAT so port 22 is directed to the pc I'm having this trouble.

Any help appreciated, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I noticed these lines in your ssh client debug output (lines 28-29):

```
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/kerem/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
```

So, may be the reason is with the keys on your client machine?
Try to regenerate them this way:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

I also would backup the old ones. Just in case.

Comment: But, this link (http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) suggests not to use ssh v1, is rsa used by ssh v2? I'm also trying to accomplish that :(

Comment: I see "-t rsa1" in the article( http://www.opennet.ru/base/sec/ssh_pubkey_auth.txt.html (in Russian)) for SSHv1. Try to generate id_dsa only...

Comment: Oh, ok then. I wasn't aware of both -t rsa and -t rsa1 existed. I've regenerated keys again, nothing changed.

Comment: And same errors in ssh client debug output?

Comment: Apparently it's still looking for that ssh v1 rsa1 key: http://pastebin.com/dD4ujmdT

Comment: May be it is worth trying to generate rsa1 with "-t rsa1"? I know, it is less secure, but I would try. Only for testing purposes.

Comment: It gives that output, http://pastebin.com/1tU1x05Y. I don't get it. Why does it try to load every single public key as if it is RSA1 key?

Comment: Hm... I looked in my own ~/.ssh/ directory and found only .known_hosts file! I'm connecting to the ssh servers normally. May be it is worth trying to delete identiti and id_(r|d)sa?.. But it seems to me to be a silly guess.

Comment: It is definitely obsessed with ssh v1 keys, I left known_hosts alone, and also deleted that too, it gives this output for both situations: http://pastebin.com/qSyQE6DT.

Comment: My ssh_config: http://pastebin.com/vm7meata almost everything is commented out (default debian config)

Comment: I have reinstalled openssh package and it now seems to accept connections and establish a successful login somehow. Configuration is the same, and I didn't generate any keys.

Thanks for answers, HUB.

Comment: I think it is worth posting your solution as an answer. Simple solution, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines can be very misleading:

```
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/kerem/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
```

Another answer suggests:

> So, may be the reason is with the keys on your client machine? Try to
>   regenerate them.

From experience, I can say that this problem can be caused by server configuration even though the messages make it look like it is strictly a client key problem. Of course, you want to check your client configuration too. But you did that and noted that nothing changed. That indicates that the problem is not the keys on your client machine (and hence the error message is misleading).

You should look at the server configuration.

For example, I found that if your user is **not** allowed by ssh config on the server, the ssh client gives this exact same (misleading) error message. If you are not allowing all users, check this:

```
sudo nano /etc/sshd_config
AllowUsers yourname@*
```

Also check denyhosts, but in my case the problem was AllowUsers in sshd_config and it gave this same misleading error message. Fixing the server fixed the problem without having to fix any keys on the client.